No funciona el DropDown en combobox control+
En un formulario tengo un combobox (cuadro combinado) que cambia de forma dinámica es decir en ejecución cada vez que lo selecciono, todo funciona bien excepto el DropDown que no se "autodespliega", envío el código que estoy utilizando.
Gracias de antemano
    Const MarcaSQL1 As String = "SELECT pres_marca.Marca FROM pres_marca;"
    Const MarcaSQL2 As String = "SELECT pres_modelo.Descripcion FROM pres_modelo WHERE (((pres_modelo.marca)=[textomarca]));"
    Const MarcaSQL3 As String = "SELECT pres_cisterna.descripcion, pres_cisterna.Marca FROM pres_cisterna WHERE (((pres_cisterna.Marca) = [Textomarca])) ORDER BY pres_cisterna.Cisterna;"

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Seleccion = 1
    Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL1
    Caracteristicas.Requery
End Sub


Private Sub Caracteristicas_AfterUpdate()
    
    If Seleccion = 1 Then
        Textomarca = Caracteristicas
        Seleccion = 2
        Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL2
        Caracteristicas.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
        Caracteristicas.Dropdown
    
    ElseIf Seleccion = 2 Then
        Textomodelo = Caracteristicas
        Seleccion = 3
        Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL3
        Caracteristicas.Requery
        Caracteristicas.Dropdown
    
    ElseIf Seleccion = 3 Then
        TextoCisterna = Caracteristicas
        Seleccion = 1
        Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL1
        Caracteristicas.Requery
        Caracteristicas.Dropdown
    
    End If
    
End Sub

